# Missplaced views every time i open the storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm using a storyboard with some ViewControllers that have elements positioned with autolayout. Every time i open the storyboard, i get misplaced views **even after i fix all of them**. I have to update the frames time and time again. Is there any way to fix this?
I'm using xcode 6.

Comment: It could be something with __Size classe__, may be you are designing your interface with a size class other than __wAny hAny__. Storyboard will be always opened in  wAny hAny by default. So that your storyboard may looks different. Could you clarify this, regarding size class?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'm using wCompact hAny. I tried to set it back to wAny hAny and i get empty views in storyboard and all the elements and constraints grayed out in the Document Outline.

Comment: wCompact hAny targets iPhone in portrait. If your app supports only iPhone(portrait only) you can use that size class. Whatever you adde to that will be specific for that device/orientation. That why it is grade out for other size class. Actually you have to design it in __wAny hAny__, will be available for all devices/orientations

Comment: I know. This is what i'm designing for. I might want to add other sizes later, but it's ok for now. Still, i'm tired of getting the Misplaced views alerts. When i'm opening storyboard it sets mine to  wCompact hAny as it should.

Comment: Is that just warning only? or it makes issues while running?

Comment: Warnings with actions (to update the frame). It works perfect while running. I update the frames (all of them) and after a while i get the same warnings again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63009/discussion-between-anil-and-dnu-mihai-florian).

Comment: Same bloody problem for me. It's incredibly frustrating cause it skews all the constraints and placements and I have to reset everything. Please let me know if you figure this out. Incredibly frustrating!

Comment: I have figured it out: it's because not using the default sizing on views (and also custom fonts might be a problem). Just make sure to have set w:Any h:Any and you'll have no more problems. You might have to redesign all of your views...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Anil Varghese pointed out the problem is the size of the view. Anything other than **wAny** **hAny** will trigger this warning when opening the storyboard file. I think it's an Xcode bug. [image]

So I had to make sure that my views are set up like in the picture above. This means designing for all sizes, so, in my case, my UI got all messed up and i had to redesign it. But it was for the best!

*When you change to wAny hAny you view elements will become invisible because they are bound to other size classes (like wCompact hAny). You need to delete those rules from the Attributes inspector.*

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and I also did not know how to fix it completely, but I found this way to make it show what I want.

"Reset to suggested constraints"

then, I set the storyboard back to "w Compact h Regular".

hope it could help you.