# Misplaced views each time Xcode restarts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm using storyboards for the first time in my app

When I close Xcode, I have 0 warnings about misplaced views or anything pertaining to my storyboard. When I restart Xcode and open the storyboard, 3 out of my 15 scenes have misplaced view warnings.

Without touching anything (other than selecting the file), I can issue a `git status` and see that the .storyboard file has changes. If I `git diff`, I see this included in multiple areas of the file:

```
<variation key="widthClass=compact" misplaced="YES">
    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="56" width="130" height="34"/>
</variation>
```

If an element already had `<variation key="widthClass=Compact"` node, then the `misplaced` attribute and `rect` node are added.

The only thing I have to do to get the warnings to go away is click on each one, make sure "Update Frame" is selected, and click "Fix Misplacement". That fixes everything until I restart Xcode.

The basic structure of my scene is:

```
UIView
    UICollectionView
        UICollectionReusableView
        UICollectionViewCell
        UICollectionViewCell
    UISegmentedControl
```

How can I prevent this from happening each time I restart?

Comment: Probably the same thing (or related) ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/6903204/499581

Comment: Its an issue of XCode as @I'L'l points out.

Comment: sometimes if you open the storyboard and change  nothing, the misplace warning occurs, you see there will be M symbol appear right away when you opened the storyboard file. dont open the sotryboard unless you want to make changes.

Comment: try restarting the computer or reloading the project as thats a Xcode problem

Comment: Are you using size classes? If not, maybe disable them?

Comment: It can be due to size class... please check any Width and Any height class...

Comment: why not just issue a git stash command so you won't need to manually reset them and then push?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missplaced views every time i open the storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354665/missplaced-views-every-time-i-open-the-storyboard)

Comment: yea if you don't need size classes, disable them entirely (same place you disable auto layout)

Comment: Often happens when you have conflicts or if you have calculated constraints that don't round to a whole number of pixels, some times you can reduce a priority somewhere and fix this

Comment: This drives me up the /wall/.

Comment: Did you find any solution on that issue? It's driving me crazy since iOS 7

Comment: Custom fonts sometimes can cause this

Comment: do you have any branches in your git.or some other people working with the same git ?

Answer (score 2):

This generally happens when you have not set the constraints properly.

Try removing all views inside the UIViewController and adding newly again along with your constraints.

Clean and run your code.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason for misplaced views is:
If you have used live views(IBDesignables) in storyboards then if you open the storyboard and quickly move to some other file before the IB has finished building all the live views then the the views get misplaced. The IB starts building the live views as soon as you view the story board in the editor. To fix the misplaced views, allow IB some time to finish building the storyboard by staying on the storyboard for few moments, and the misplaced views will get fixed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12947482)

Comment: @HiDeo: I was trying to answer the question but my selection of words was not proper I guess. I have edited the post to make more sense (I hope!)

Answer (score 2):

In my case it happens for all labels / buttons with custom fonts and intrinsic (not explicitly defined) sizes. Looks like an Xcode bug.

Comment: It is a Xcode bug, and it appears still be there/back in Xcode 8.2.1. Workaround: use code for views.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue before, and I suppose it's not our fault, it's just a Xcode's bug.

If your `.storyboard` file changed but you didn't touch anything, just select the file and select the Xcode menu `Source Control` -> `Discard Changes in "xxxx.storyboard"...`, it should be work :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused when you add constraints that don't fit the actual screen size at run time.
for example : if you have a UIButton with width that exceeds screen width (let's say width 600) and you add fixed width constraint to that UIButton but no leading or trailing constraints , Xcode won't give you warnings as there are no conflicts, but when you actually run the app on a device or simulator with screen width less than 600, Xcode will automatically adjust UIButton width to fit the screen width which is less than 600, causing your layout constraints to change to what fitted the screen at runtime

Answer (score 0):

If you are using size classes then either your constraints are not up to the mark (according to all device type if Any-Any). If not then try to adjust the frame or constraints and check once again.

Auto layout may also cause this issue.
You will get all the information regarding the warning once you click on them.

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the same problem with my previous app. What I noticed is that the size of storyboards matters here.

This is Xcode issue.

If we use storyboard of **any width any height**, this problem doesn't occur.
If you are using storyboards of size **Compact width regular height**, this issue occurs.

So try to use **default storyboard sizes** in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

1. click to preview a regular file (not `.xib` or `.storyboard` file)
2. quit Xcode
3. run `git checkout .`
4. restart Xcode

the `.storyboard` file is not modified now.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix may be to simply allow Xcode to choose constraints for you, then go back and check what it has chosen to be sure it will work for you.

In storyboard:

- **Select View Controller giving you problems**
- **Resolve Auto Layout Issues (bottom right)**
- **Selected Views: Reset to Suggested
  Constraints**

To check what constraints have been reset:

- **Select each View within controller**
- **Constraints Inspector (top right)**
- **scroll down and examine constraints**

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom of the storyboard we have the option to select the size class. If I change the option from wRegular hRegular to any other option I get the similar issue. I don't know the reason for this.

Try to resolve it by selecting the same size class after opening the project as you have selected before closing the project.

For example, if you have selected the size class as wCompact hRegular for iPhone and you have closed your project. After opening the project again, you will see that the size class has changed to wRegular hRegular. Because of this the view objects change. Select wCompact hRegular again to resolve the issue.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -3):

First check you have implement all constraints.If all constraint are correct then delete related constraint and rebut again.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but you can easily solve it by just using "fix misplacement". You do not need to worry because this happened when you are not using normal size.